# make an image (background-image CSS) into PHP variable value

Tags: php, css, html

I want to make a product gallery like 5 products, each has their own background-image attribute
I use loop to insert the product image, so I want to make it each loop will have different background-image

I'm thinking of using IF statement like so

```
 <?php

 $bg = 0;
 $bg1 = "url('img1.jpg')";
 $bg2 = "url('img2.jpg')";
 $bg3 = "url('img3.jpg')";
 $bg4 = "url('img4.jpg')";
 $bg5 = "url('img5.jpg')";

 if ($bg = 0){ 
  echo " <div style='background-image :$bg1 ;'>" ;
      $bg = 1;
     } else if ($bg= 1) { 
       echo " <div style='background-image :$bg2 ;'>" ;
      $bg = 2;
     } else if ($bg= 2 ) { 
       echo " <div style='background-image :$bg3 ;'>" ;
      $bg = 3;
     } else if ($bg= 3 ) { 
       echo " <div style='background-image :$bg4 ;'>" ;
      $bg = 4;
     } else if ($bg= 4 ) { 
      echo " <div style='background-image :$bg5 ;'>" ;
       $bg = 0;
     }


    echo "   </div> " ;

    code for product images
?>
```

above is the simplified code I wrote, it doesn't work.
if anyone has a different but much simpler solution it will be appreciated

note : the image files are in the same directory with this php file

thank you

Comment: You're going to want to use an array, not variables with names like `$bg1`. And you don't even have a loop, yet, so you're not looping over anything right now. Also, you need to use `===` or `==` for comparison, not `=` (`=` is the assignment operator), and use `switch`/`case` instead of that huge block of `if`/`else` statements. Honestly, it looks like you need to spend some time with an introductory tutorial.

Comment: What about just `echo "<div style='background-image : url(\"img{$bg}.jpg\")'>";`? Or i guess conditional on just the 4th one..

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to using img tags? This, in my opinion, would be a better solution:

Code:

```
<?php

$images=Array(
    "img1.jpg",
    "img2.jpg",
    "img3.jpg",
    "img4.jpg",
    "img5.jpg"
);

//
print "\n<br> Code: \n<pre>\n".RenderThoseImages($images)."\n</pre>";

//
function RenderThoseImages($images)
{
    //
    $s="";

    //
    foreach($images as $image){
        $s.="\n<div><img src=\"{$image}\"></div>";
    }

    return $s;
}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
<br> Code: 
<pre>

<div><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="img3.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="img4.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="img5.jpg"></div>
</pre>
```

The main reason being that when you use the background-image CSS, you're also responsible for grabbing the image dimensions in PHP and rendering height/width into the div CSS as well, or possibly creating some javascript to fix it after loading, creating unneeded headache.